# Image swiping and changing with buttons as well

Tags: android, android-viewpager, android-imageview

I am trying to make a gallery app.I have two buttons for 'next' and 'back' when i press on next button the i need to show the next image also i need to change the images by swiping. I have tried with image adapter. but i dont know to change the images with buttons.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use **[this](http://sandyandroidtutorials.blogspot.in/2013/06/custom-gallery-view.html)** tutorial for your reference to implement the **Gallery with buttons**.

In this tutorial I use **Arrow** buttons for **next** and **previous**.

I implement some more functionality in this tutorial.

like:

**thumb** and **full image** view in the screen.

from thumb images which you select that **highlight**.

By **Arrow buttons** also you change the images(next/previous).

Answer (score 7):

**You can create new class to detect swipe and create an instant to use it.**

> public class SwipeDetect implements OnTouchListener {
>
> ```
> private final GestureDetector gestureDetector = new GestureDetector(new GestureListener());
>
> public boolean onTouch(final View view, final MotionEvent motionEvent) {
>     return gestureDetector.onTouchEvent(motionEvent);
> }
>
> private final class GestureListener extends SimpleOnGestureListener {
>
>     private static final int SWIPE_THRESHOLD = 100;
>     private static final int SWIPE_VELOCITY_THRESHOLD = 100;
>
>     @Override
>     public boolean onDown(MotionEvent e) {
>         return true;
>     }
>
>     @Override
>     public boolean onFling(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2, float velocityX, float velocityY) {
>         boolean result = false;
>         try {
>             float diffY = e2.getY() - e1.getY();
>             float diffX = e2.getX() - e1.getX();
>             if (Math.abs(diffX) > Math.abs(diffY)) {
>                 if (Math.abs(diffX) > SWIPE_THRESHOLD && Math.abs(velocityX) > SWIPE_VELOCITY_THRESHOLD) {
>                     if (diffX > 0) {
>                         onSwipeRight();
>                     } else {
>                         onSwipeLeft();
>                     }
>                 }
>             } else {
>                 if (Math.abs(diffY) > SWIPE_THRESHOLD && Math.abs(velocityY) > SWIPE_VELOCITY_THRESHOLD) {
>                     if (diffY > 0) {
>                         onSwipeBottom();
>                     } else {
>                         onSwipeTop();
>                     }
>                 }
>             }
>         } catch (Exception exception) {
>             exception.printStackTrace();
>         }
>         return result;
>     }
> }
>
> public void onSwipeRight() {
> }
>
> public void onSwipeLeft() {
> }
>
> public void onSwipeTop() {
> }
>
> public void onSwipeBottom() {
> } }
> ```

**Use it:**

```
YourImageView.setOnTouchListener(new SwipeDetect() {
            public void onSwipeRight() {
                //Your code here
            }

            public void onSwipeLeft() {
                //Your code here
            }
        });
```

*You can use it for imageview, layout...*

Answer (score 0):

Try with [this](http://developer.android.com/design/patterns/swipe-views.html) one for starting point. You can also implement the tutorial shown [here](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2011/08/horizontal-view-swiping-with-viewpager.html).